# Stopwatch cocos2d-x (Android & iOS)

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x

I'm currently facing a problem.

I create a games where user can race within a level, and there's stopwatch to count the time user finished the level.

I use this code snippet for convert the counter to stopwatch

```
 void update(float dt)
{

    if (!paused)
    {
        fcheckbutton+=dt;
        ftimer+=dt;

        if (ftimer >= 0.01f)
        {
            this->timer();
            ftimer = 0.0f;
        }
    }
}



     void timer()
        {
        m_timer++;
        int milliseconds = m_timer%60;
        int seconds = (m_timer/60)%60;
        int minutes = m_timer/3600;

        CCString * P1Time = CCString::createWithFormat("%02d:%02d:%02d", minutes,seconds,milliseconds);

        m_label->setString(P1Time->getCString());
        }
```

I called this function in my update method...

The problem is in every device (iOS and Android) the stopwatch produce various result...

In my test case, if user doesn't make any input, he should be lost in about 32 secs....

iOS (iPhone 4) is the closest one, with stopwatch ~32 secs

But in Android device, The result is vary..

Google Nexus S 28 seccs

new Google Nexus 7 18 secs

Galaxy Note 30 secs

It's important that stopwatch must be sync in every device, because i have a leaderboard based on user's stopwatch result.

How do I supposed to do this?

EDIT: update to call timer method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you update your m_timer variable? I think the problem is that some device has lower FPS.

Comment: I've edited my question. I called the timer method inside update. Yeah I noticed that. on New Nexus 7, it has 30 fps.... What's the solution?

Comment: use _dt_ passed in update as your passed time counter, now If you have for example 0.9f in ftimer, then in next call 1.9f you are loosing 0.9f of time.

Comment: done that. Is it really matter? I don't use                    m_timer+=dt

Comment: Yes is matter. If you have update called every 1.9f you will lose about ~ 30 s every minute.

Comment: Hai, thanks for your answer. Sorry for not getting back to you sooner.  I really should put dt as my parameter